# java.util.Date shows different values with the same input parameters

Tags: date, maven, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, tycho

I try to System.out the same strings

```
System.out.println(" DATE 29 " + new Date(1330462800000l) + " Date 01 "
                + new Date(1330549200000l));
```

but I have different results when I check it in Build(running in console mode) and when i run application from eclipse.

output from eclipse(seems like it is correct result):

> DATE 29 Wed Feb 29 00:00:00 EET 2012 Date 01 Thu Mar 01 00:00:00 EET
>   2012

output from build(console mode)

> DATE 29 Tue Feb 28 23:00:00 EET 2012 Date 01 Wed Feb 29 23:00:00 EET
>   2012

Sorry for stupid question, but do you have any ideas about possible reasons?

PS:I use maven+tycho to make build, packaging-type eclipse-repository.(if it realy matter)

EDIT:
In Eclipse I looked at timeZone value:

```
Calendar calendar=Calendar.getInstance();
System.out.println("!!!time zone before: " +   calendar.getTimeZone());
```

> !!!time zone before: 
>   sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Minsk",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=121,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Minsk,offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=1,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=1]]

then I set timezone with hardcoded zoneId and made build

```
calendar.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("Europe/Minsk"));
```

haven't any results

EDIT: I use different versions and architectures of jres in build and eclipse..Could it be the reason?
EDIT:

```
System.out.println("!!!!!! system.timezone " + System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
System.setProperty("user.timezone", "Europe/Minsk");
System.out.println("!!!!!! system.timezone " + System.getProperty("user.timezone"));
```

> !!!!!! system.timezone Europe/Minsk
>
> !!!!!! system.timezone Europe/Minsk!!!calendar time after zone:
>   sun.util.calendar.ZoneInfo[id="Europe/Minsk",offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,transitions=121,lastRule=java.util.SimpleTimeZone[id=Europe/Minsk,offset=7200000,dstSavings=3600000,useDaylight=true,startYear=0,startMode=2,startMonth=2,startDay=-1,startDayOfWeek=1,startTime=7200000,startTimeMode=1,endMode=2,endMonth=9,endDay=-1,endDayOfWeek=1,endTime=7200000,endTimeMode=1]]

Correct timezone. but date is still wrong

Comment: Timezone settings in the environment where the VM is running.

Comment: Sorry, but could they  be defferent for the same machine?

Comment: Yep, TZ is part of the processes' environment and can be changed. Although looking at it "EET" is probably the TZ and it is the same for both, so could be a red herring.

Comment: Did you know that there is a history view that allows to see edits to the problem? You should consider merging the edits into the original question to make it more readable

Answer (score 1):

Add to test:

```
System.out.println(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeZone());
```

or

```
System.getProperty("user.timezone");
```

Java timezone can be set by system property user.timezone, see [Java system properties](http://www.mindspring.com/~mgrand/java-system-properties.htm) for details.

For time use [joda time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). You can redefine timezone for all joda objects:

```
DateTimeZone.setDefault(DateTimeZone.UTC);
```

Comment: added in question . As for Joda time - then i can't to add new libraries to project :(

Comment: So try timezone. Check System.getProperty("user.timezone")

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_330_462_800_000L )     // Convert count-of-milliseconds-since-epoch to an `Instant`, a moment on the timeline in UTC.
       .atZone( ZoneId.of( "Europe/Minsk" ) )  // Adjust into another time zone. Same moment, different wall-clock time.
```

## Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes that are now legacy, supplanted by the java.time classes. Among the many flaws is the `Date::toString` method’s application of the JVM’s current default time zone dynamically while generating a string. A `Date` represents a moment in UTC but this well-intentioned anti-feature brings confusion. The JVM’s current default time zone can change at any moment, even *during runtime*, so you may see various results.

## java.time

Use `java.time.Instant` in place of `java.util.Date`.

### `Instant`

The [`Instant`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) class represents a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond) (up to nine (9) digits of a decimal fraction).

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_330_462_800_000L ) ;
```

Learn to think and **work in UTC primarily**. Think of UTC as the *One True Time™*. All other time zones are mere variations on that theme. While on the job as a programmer, forget about your personal local time, and stop converting back-and-forth between zones as that can drive you batty. Focus on UTC in your programming and logging.

### `ZonedDateTime`

To view that same moment through the lens of another time zone, apply a `ZoneId` to get a `ZonedDateTime` object. We still have the same moment, the same point on the timeline, but with another wall-clock time.

```
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of( "Europe/Minsk" ) ;
ZonedDateTime zdt = instant.atZone( z ) ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://ideone.com/WbwG0n).

> instant.toString(): 2012-02-28T21:00:00Z
>
> zdt.toString(): 2012-02-29T00:00+03:00[Europe/Minsk]

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).